# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing

Tags: java, encryption

I need to store the encrypted password in DB **without storing any key or salt**. And I want to make sure it's safer as well even though it's a two-way encryption. So after googling a bit, I have created a sample program to test it. My idea is to create a custom JPA AttributeConverter class to manage this.

**Following is the program:**

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto {

    private static final String _algorithm = "AES";
    private static final String _password = "_pasword*";
    private static final String _salt = "_salt*";
    private static final String _keygen_spec = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static final String _cipher_spec = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        Key key = getKey();
        System.out.println(key.toString());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(_cipher_spec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
        System.out.println("Encrypted value of "+data+": "+encryptedValue);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static void decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = getKey();
        System.out.println(key.toString());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(_cipher_spec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        System.out.println("Decrypted value of "+encryptedData+": "+decryptedValue);
    }

    private static Key getKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(_keygen_spec);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(_password.toCharArray(), _salt.getBytes(), 65536, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), _algorithm);
        return secret;
    }

    public static void main(String []str) throws Exception {
        String value = encrypt("India@123");
        decrypt(value);
    }
}
```

But its throwing the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17111
Encrypted value of India@123: iAv1fvjMnJqilg90rGztXA==
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17111
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:469)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:802)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
    at org.lp.test.Crypto.decrypt(Crypto.java:37)
    at org.lp.test.Crypto.main(Crypto.java:54)
```

I am not able to figure this out.

**I have rectified the exception based on @Luke Park's answer I have created a JPA AttributeConverter as below:**

```
    import java.security.Key;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class CryptoJPAConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static final String _algorithm = "AES";
    private static final String _password = "_pasword*";
    private static final String _salt = "_salt*";
    private static final String _keygen_spec = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static final String _cipher_spec = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String clearText) {
        Key key;
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            key = getKey();
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(_cipher_spec);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(clearText.getBytes());
            String encryptedValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String encryptedText) {
        Key key;
        try {
            key = getKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(_cipher_spec);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
            byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decordedValue);
            String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Key getKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(_keygen_spec);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(_password.toCharArray(), _salt.getBytes(), 65536, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), _algorithm);
        return secret;
    }
}
```

I have used the two way encryption because I need to pass the password as clear text to Java mail client.

Suggestion and comments are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` but you are not passing an IV to your `cipher.init` calls.

CBC mode requires a random IV for each encryption operation, you should generate this using `SecureRandom` each time you encrypt, and pass the value in as an `IvParameterSpec`.  You'll need the same IV for decryption.  It is common to prepend the IV to the ciphertext and retrieve when required.

On a seperate note, encrypting passwords is really quite a terrible idea.  The fact that you have to ask this question at all somewhat proves that you aren't in a position to be making security-related decisions.  Do yourself and your project a favour and **hash your passwords** instead.  PBKDF2 and bcrypt are both decent ways of doing so.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue. I have to decrypt the password and pass it to another system. So I need two-way encryption. I will update my question with the solution I applied based on issue that you pointed out